# Find overlap of two lists, preserving sequence order

Tags: python, list

I've found many methods of finding list intersections here, but I'm having trouble finding an efficient way to find the intersection when order is taken into account.

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
list2 = [7, 6, 3, 4, 5, 8]
```

The function should return `[3, 4, 5]`

I would already know there is only one overlapping sequence, and I would know its minimum length, but not its exact length.

Comment: Sounds like a [longest common subsequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem) problem to me.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, you are correct, now that I know what to call it I've found some algorithms.

Comment: Hmm... I was hoping that by knowing there was only one subsequence in common and having a minimum length for it, I could avoid having to use an O(MN) algorithm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the [Longest Common Subsequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem) algorithm; the following uses dynamic programming to find the elements in O(NM) time (for sequences of length N and M):

```
def lcs(a, b):
    tbl = [[0 for _ in range(len(b) + 1)] for _ in range(len(a) + 1)]
    for i, x in enumerate(a):
        for j, y in enumerate(b):
            tbl[i + 1][j + 1] = tbl[i][j] + 1 if x == y else max(
                tbl[i + 1][j], tbl[i][j + 1])
    res = []
    i, j = len(a), len(b)
    while i and j:
        if tbl[i][j] == tbl[i - 1][j]:
            i -= 1
        elif tbl[i][j] == tbl[i][j - 1]:
            j -= 1
        else:
            res.append(a[i - 1])
            i -= 1
            j -= 1
    return res[::-1]
```

Demo:

```
>>> def lcs(a, b):
...     tbl = [[0 for _ in range(len(b) + 1)] for _ in range(len(a) + 1)]
...     for i, x in enumerate(a):
...         for j, y in enumerate(b):
...             tbl[i + 1][j + 1] = tbl[i][j] + 1 if x == y else max(
...                 tbl[i + 1][j], tbl[i][j + 1])
...     res = []
...     i, j = len(a), len(b)
...     while i and j:
...         if tbl[i][j] == tbl[i - 1][j]:
...             i -= 1
...         elif tbl[i][j] == tbl[i][j - 1]:
...             j -= 1
...         else:
...             res.append(a[i - 1])
...             i -= 1
...             j -= 1
...     return res[::-1]
... 
>>> list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
>>> list2 = [7, 6, 3, 4, 5, 8]
>>> lcs(list1, list2)
[3, 4, 5]
```

This will find the subsequence regardless of location and if other elements are mixed in between:

```
>>> lcs([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [7, 3, 6, 4, 8, 5])
[3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: If I already know the minimum length of the subsequence, and that there is only one, is there any way to do better than an O(MN) algorithm?

Comment: @prooffreader: You still have to find those elements, which means you have to scan both sequences.

Comment: @prooffreader: the minimum length doesn't really get you anything here. Knowing the *maximum* length would let you stop searching early in stage one and move to stage two (reconstructing the sub-sequence) a little earlier.